# Using gh API to get author and commit date

Tags: github, github-api

I have a url like this: https://github.com/david26694/cluster-experiments/blob/4e50f067d2ae4946e0764a7e787275a6c8af4aab/README.md

I would like to use gh api to get the last commit date and the user who committed in that file.

I'm trying something like this:

```
gh api /repos/david26694/cluster-experiments/commits
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I filter by the README file, in this case?